# Error while date conversion in rails application "TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on date conversion and trying to find out various dates in a week. In Rails console everything works fine but Web Application fails with error

> ***TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer***

**Rails Version: 5.2.4.1**

Here is output of browser web-console

```
d = Date.new(2021, 10, 11) # or Date.today
=> Mon, 11 Oct 2021

>> d.beginning_of_week  # or same issue with d.next_week

TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer
    from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_and_time/calculations.rb:258:in `-'
    from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_and_time/calculations.rb:258:in `days_to_week_start'
    from /home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_and_time/calculations.rb:266:in `beginning_of_week'
    from /home/xyz/checkout/my-app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:109:in `working_time'
```

Rails console works fine

```
[1] pry(main)> d = Date.new(2021, 10, 11)
=> Mon, 11 Oct 2021
[2] pry(main)> d.beginning_of_week
=> Mon, 11 Oct 2021
```

Comment: Can you post the code from `working_time` method inside `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`. There seems to be some kind of operations taking place.

Comment: The code is pretty simple in working_time                                                                ```def working_time
    due_date = Time.now
    @admin = current_admin
    start_time = Time.now
    current_week = due_date.to_date.beginning_of_week  <--- it break here ```

Comment: The logs talk about `days_to_week_start` and `-` too.

Comment: This message is from date_time library

Comment: This is the culprit Time::DAYS_INTO_WEEK.deep_transform_keys! {|x| x.to_s.camelcase}. This issue is now fixed